# Python 3 - Open Directory via Tkinter FileDialog, and join pdfs in selected directory into one PDF file

Tags: python, file, tkinter, dialog, operating-system

I am trying to use the following code to select a directory with pdf files present using Tkinters filedialog.askdirectory()

```
def joinpdf():
    newdir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    pdfFiles = []
    for filename in os.listdir(newdir):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfFiles.append(filename)
    pdfFiles.sort(key = str.lower)

    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for filename in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
            pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

    pdfOutput = open('allminutes.pdf', 'wb')
    pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
    pdfOutput.close()
```

When I open the directory, I am faced with the following error:

```
pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: testing.pdf
```

Testing.pdf is a name of one of the pdfs in the folder I opened with the Tkinter Filedialog, so I am thinking it is finding the file as it has discovered the name of the file correctly, but I don't know why this error is being displayed

Thanks to anyone who can provide assitance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to a relevant method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join your filename and your directory using `os.path.join(newdir, filename)` or use `abspath` to get the absolute filepath.
Then it should work.

```
pdfFiles.append(os.path.join(newdir, filename))
```

The FileNotFoundError occurs as your file is most likely not inside the current directory of your script, so `pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')` looks inside your current working directory.

Another (not really common) approach would be changing directory context to `newdir` and then continue the work.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation.